# conducting a multilevel model with a continuous variable and categorical variable in r (+ post hoc)

Tags: r, regression, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, bonferroni

I conducted a study in which I presented three types/blocks of visual stimuli (neutral stimuli in baseline, negative stimuli, neutral stimuli following negative stimuli).
To examine the relationship between borderline personality feature (continuous variable) and response to stimuli of each block, 
I conducted multilevel model.

```
MAIN <- lmer(response~BPD*block+(1|ID), data= test)
```

And then to control for the continuous measures as covariates (CESD, STAI,STAXI_A), I inserted them into the formula.

```
m <- lmer(response~STAXI_A+CESD+STAI_A+BPD*block+(1|ID), data= test)
```

For post-hoc, three Bonferroni-corrected multilevel linear random regressions were conducted, because significant interaction effect could be due to association between BP feature and responses to neutral stimuli at baseline, response to negative stimuli, or response to neutral stimuli following negative stimuli.
For post-hoc regressions, I again set predictor as BPD and outcome as responses to each context.

```
test<- test %>%
filter(block !="emo",block !="neu") # to only include baseline for this analysis
mbase<- lmer(response ~BPDCen+(1|ID), data=test)
summary(mbase)

test<- test %>%
filter(block !="base",block !="neu") # to only include emo (negative stimuli) for this analysis
memo <- lmer(response ~BPD+(1|ID), data=test)
summary(memo)

test<- test %>%
filter(block !="emo",block !="base")# to only include neutral stimuli for this analysis
mneu <-  lmer(response ~BPDCen+(1|ID), data=test)
summary(mneu)
```

Then I did a Bonferroni correction for testing the hypothesis three time with same outcome variable by dividing the p value by 3 (0.05/3).

Please please inform me if I did something wrong...!

Thankyou so much people.

Comment: What is `BPDCen` ? Also what are `STAXI_A`, `CESD` and `STAI_A`  and are they confounders, competing exposures or mediators ?

Comment: They are all continuous variables and BPDCen is a mean-centered predictor variable. STAXI_A, CESD, and STAI_A are all continuous covariates. Thank you.

Comment: But are they confounders, mediators or competing exposures?